# Dom cloneNode does not work

Tags: javascript, html

Actual problem is I want to generate five images in left side and clone it to right side, my code is:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <style>
        img{
            position: absolute;
        }
        div{
            position: absolute;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
        #rightSide { left: 500px; 
                    border-left: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        // var numberOfFaces = 5;
        // var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
        function generateFaces(){
            var numberOfFaces = 5;
            var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++){
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = "smile.png";

                var randomTop = Math.random() * 400;
                var randomLeft = Math.random() * 400;
                img.style.top = randomTop + "px";
                img.style.left = randomLeft + "px";
                theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
            }
            var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
            leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
            document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild("leftSideImages");

        }

        window.onload = generateFaces;
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
    <p>click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
    <div id = "leftSide">
    </div>
    <div id = "rightSide">
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Error message is jspart4.html:36 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at generateFaces (jspart4.html:36)

What is the problem?

and then I want to play this game, if click the extra smile, generate more, or show "game over",my code is :

```
function generateFaces(){

        var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++){
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = "smile.png";

            var randomTop = Math.random() * 400;
            var randomLeft = Math.random() * 400;
            img.style.top = randomTop + "px";
            img.style.left = randomLeft + "px";
            theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
        }
        var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
        leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
        leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
        document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild(leftSideImages);
        var theBody = document.getElementByTagName("body")[0];
        theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            while (theBody.firstChild){
                theBody.removeChild(theBody.firstChild);
            }
            numberOfFaces += 5;
            generateFaces();
        }
        theBody.onclick = function gameover(){
            alert("Game Over");
            thBody.onclick = null;
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;

        }

    }
```

But when I click extra smile or body, nothing happens, could you help solve it?

Comment: there is a delete button after your question. below tags check it you will find it

Comment: Add your code in question not in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you made mistake

```
document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild("leftSideImages");
```

Remove `""` from `leftSideImages` like this

```
document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild(leftSideImages);
```

```js
 // var numberOfFaces = 5;
        // var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
        function generateFaces(){
            var numberOfFaces = 5;
            var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++){
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = "smile.png";

                var randomTop = Math.random() * 400;
                var randomLeft = Math.random() * 400;
                img.style.top = randomTop + "px";
                img.style.left = randomLeft + "px";
                theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
            }
            var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
            leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
            document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild(leftSideImages);

        }

        window.onload = generateFaces;
```

```css
img{
            position: absolute;
        }
        div{
            position: absolute;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
        #rightSide { left: 500px; 
                    border-left: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
    <p>click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
    <div id = "leftSide">
    </div>
    <div id = "rightSide">
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I just start using stackoverflow these two days.

Comment: I have ac your answer, and edit the new question, thanks